# Símbolo sumindo ao salvar imagem do gráfico

Tags: r, ggplot2, gráfico

Nas anotações inseridas pelo argumento `annotate` no gráfico abaixo em uma delas possui o símbolo "≠", porém ao salvar a imagem como PDF o símbolo some e aparece "..." no lugar.

Gostaria de mantê-lo mesmo após salvar, existe alguma maneira?

Segue o comando utilizado e uma imagem ilustrando o exemplo.

```
    library(ggplot2)
    dt <- data.frame(periodo = c("JUN", "JUL"), 
             peso = c(9.38, 26.14,16.27,47.71))
    dt$Variedade <- rep(c("6654", "9002"), each = nrow(dt)/2)
    dt$periodo <- factor(dt$periodo, levels = c("JUN", "JUL"))
    theme_patrick <- function(){ 
    theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),
      axis.text.y=element_blank(),
      axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
      axis.text.x=element_text(face = "bold", color = "black", size = 15),
      legend.text = element_text(size = 15),
      plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold", hjust = 0, vjust = 2))}
   ggplot(dt, aes(x = periodo, y = peso)) +
   geom_col(aes(fill = Variedade), position = "dodge") +
   geom_label(aes(label = peso, colour = Variedade),
         fill = NA,
         position = position_dodge(width = 1),
         size = 5,
         fontface = "bold", vjust = -0.1, 
         show.legend = FALSE) +
   labs(x = "Período", y = "", title = "", subtitle = "Evolução peso")+
   scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,80))+
   scale_fill_manual(values = c("brown1", "blue")) +
   scale_colour_manual(values = c("brown1", "blue")) +
   theme_patrick()+
   annotate(geom = "label", x = c("JUN","JUL"), y = c(20,40), label = c("≠6.89 kg","≠21.57 
   kg"), fontface = "bold", size = 5)+
   annotate(geom = "label", x = c(1.89,2.39), y = c(28.3,50), label = c("+16.76 kg","+31.44 
   kg"), colour = c("brown1","blue"), fontface = "italic", size = 5)
```

[image: Gráfico ilustrativo]

Comment: Tá com cara que a fonte usada para exibir na tela é diferente da utilizada no PDF, e a segunda fonte não tem esse símbolo. Sugiro escolher uma fonte específica, aí vai aparecer nas duas mídias, ou em nenhuma.

Comment: @epx o formato da fonte que fala é o tipo de letra ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nem todas as fontes e glifos são suportados pelo driver `postscript`. A forma mais simples de resolver é usar o driver `cairo`. Ele não é suportado pelo `ggsave`, então abra o dispositivo manualmente. Eis um exemplo mínimo com seus dados:

```
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(dt, aes(x = periodo, y = peso, fill = Variedade)) +
       geom_col(position = "dodge") +
       annotate(geom = "label", x = c("JUN","JUL"), y = c(20,40), label = c("≠6.89 kg","≠21.57 kg"))

cairo_pdf("plot.pdf", width = 6, height = 4)
p
dev.off()
```

Comment: Carlos ao rodar o comando não aparece ao final o gráfico plotado, como posso abri-lo manualmente ? ele vai para uma pasta específica ? Aparece somente "null device 1 "

Comment: Não aparece na tela porque o gráfico foi enviado diretamente para o dispositivo `cairo_pdf`. O arquivo *plot.pdf*  foi salvo no seu diretório de trabalho. Para exibir o gráfico, só rodar `p` (fora do dispositivo aberto).